# AWS AMPLIFY: Lambda Function: Empty Secret Name even after Setting it

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

I have a lambda function and Secret key configured for my Lambda Function.
When I try to access the Secret key from my source code, I get an empty array []. I am unsure why I am getting an Empty array even after configuring the Secret key.

```
const getStripeSecretKey = async () => {
  const { Parameters } = await new aws.SSM()
    .getParameters({
      Names: ["stripe_secret"],
      WithDecryption: true,
    })
    .promise();
  console.log(" I am here");
  console.log(Parameters);
};
```

Any Insights and help are highly Appreciated. Besides, thanks for taking the time to go over this issue . You're the best.

Tried so Far:

1. Attaching Policies
2. Reading Documentation
3. Scratching and banging mah head

Comment: Are you sure the key is saved as a secret? In the AWS Secrets Manager? If so, then you should not use aws.SSM() client, but aws.SecretsManager() client and method `getSecretValue`. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SecretsManager.html#getSecretValue-property

Comment: I'd suggest looking wherever you expect it to see in the console, and finding it as a means of ascertaining its existence.